# How to make a synchonous call to webassembly

Tags: javascript, webassembly

Normally when doing a webassembly call it will be called asynchronously with the following pattern:

> API <-> Web Worker (async) <-> WASM

However, I have a use case where I need to call wasm with a synchronous call: in this case because the CopyToClipboard operation needs to be synchronous. Is this possible to do in webassembly? What would be the simplest example of doing a synchronous call in js<->wasm?

Answer (score 1):

Do that by having the WebAssembly module instantiated directly in the main thread, without a worker. There the calls are synchronous.